# PHP Always run function

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get some errors returned in JSON format.  So, I made a class level var:

```
public $errors = Array();
```

So, lower down in the script, different  functions might return an error, and add their error to the $errors array.  But, I have to use return; in some places to stop the script after an error occurs.

So, when I do that, how can I still run my last error function that will return all the gathered errors?  How can I get around the issue of having to stop the script, but still wanting to return the errors for why I needed to stop the script?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PHP5+ your class can have a **destructor** method:

```
public function __destruct() {
    die(var_dump($this->errors));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Really bare bones skeleton:

```
$errors = array();

function add_error($message, $die = false) {
  global $errors;
  $errors[] = $message;
  if ($die) {
    die(implode("\n", $errors));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [register a shutdown function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php).

Comment: Didn ' t assume this that the script is 'completed'?

Comment: Yes, you would need to call `exit()` when an error condition is a fatal one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the errors to the current `$_SESSION`
2. Add the latest errors to any kind of `cache`, `XML` or some storage

If the code 'stops':

> // code occurs error
>
> `die(print_r($errors))`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick involving **do{}**.

```
do {
    if(something) {
        // add error
    }
    if(something_else) {
        // add error
        break;
    }
    if(something) {
        // add error
    }
}while(0);

// check/print errors
```

Notice **break**, you can use it to break out of the **do** scope at any time, after which you have the final error returning logic.
Or you could just what's inside **do{}** inside a function, and use **return** instead of **break**, which would be even better. Or yes, even better, a class with a destructor.